# php page starts bash script to run in the background and not timeout

Tags: php, bash, exec, shell-exec

I have seen this question on here before so I am sorry for the repetition but I have still not found an answer to my problem.

I have a bash script that takes a while to run.  It needs to be passed variables set by a user on a webpage (don't worry there will be plenty of validation for security etc)

I can get the bash file to start but it dies after 20 seconds maybe when run from the webpage.

When run from the terminal.. runs absolutely fine.

Ok so I have the following:

```
$bashFile = shell_exec('./CoinCreationBashFile.sh "'.$coinName.'" "'.$coinNameAbreviation.'" "'.$blockReward.'" "'.$blockSpacing.'" "'.$targetTimespan.'" "'.$totalCoins.'" "'.$firstBitAddy.'" "'.$seedNode.'" "'.$seedName.'" "'.$headline.'" ');
```

Now this executes the bash file, but I read up about [Shell_exec php with nohup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4929827/shell-exec-php-with-nohup) and came up with the following:

```
$bashFile = shell_exec('nohup ./CoinCreationBashFile.sh "'.$coinName.'" "'.$coinNameAbreviation.'" "'.$blockReward.'" "'.$blockSpacing.'" "'.$targetTimespan.'" "'.$totalCoins.'" "'.$firstBitAddy.'" "'.$seedNode.'" "'.$seedName.'" "'.$headline.'" >/dev/null 2>&1 &');
```

But this still died after short time :(

So read up about set_time_limit and max_execution_time and set these to like 10000000 in the php.ini file.... Yet still no joy :(

Just want to run a bash script without it timing out and exiting.  Don't really want to have to put an intermediate step in there but someone suggested I look at ZeroMQ to "detach worker from process" so I may have to go this route.

many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dont try runging a script via browser if they take more then 60 seconds instead try running this with SSH or as a cronjob.

Comment: I can pass variables to the cronjob from the php page? and this was NOT useful... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4918982/what-is-the-code-to-call-a-cron-job-from-php any answer to that?

Comment: can't do a cron job as i don't want to periodically run it... need to run on request

Comment: For anyone else who stumbles on this scenario, my workaround was to get the php page to write the necessary variables to a small .txt file in a usually empty directory.  Then setup a cron job to check if this directory contained a file.  Extract the variables and run the script as root from the cron job.  Really not to much work once figured out.  Many thanks for the advice Ethan